# What is the difference in operation between . and ^ and ^(.*)$?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What is the difference in operation between:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

I know that "." means any character and "^" beginning of string.

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's understand how landing page is matched.

For landing page URI pattern is `^$` in .htaccess, `^/$` in Apache config. Thus you can safely use `^/?$` universally.

1. Your first rewrite rule will match **every URL (including landing page i.e. `http://domain.com/`)**.
2. Your second rewrite rule will match **every URL (except landing page)**. As single DOT will not match `^$` URI pattern.
3. Your third rewrite rule will also match **every URL (including landing page i.e. `http://domain.com`)** but has an unnecessary capturing group and longish version of just `^`.